# import csv into mysql using myphpadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a csv file into mysql database. The database contains 5 tables.

1. Table 1 has a primary key
2. Table 2 has its own primary and table 1's primary as foreign key
3. Table 3 has its own primary and table 2's primary as foreign key
4. Table 4 has its own primary and table 3's primary as foreign key
5. Table 5 has its own primary and table 4's primary as foreign key

Now, I am trying to import data into table 4. The data has "," as delimiter and is in a csv file. When I directly import, I have an issue of phpmyadmin just spinning and doing nothing. My question is, is this the right away?
Second question is, Do I need to fill the foreign in table 4, and fill foreign, primary keys in tables 1,2,3?

Answer (score 0):

If the values entered into the foreign keyed column of table 4 are not already there in table 3 you have to add them there first and by similar logic corresponding values to table 2 and table 1.

Comment: So what you are saying is, I go to individual tables (ie import data separately), fill up the primary key, and go to next table, put the primary and foreign key (primary key from previous table) and go on like this?